# MYSQL Error 1064 on INSERT INTO with CTE

Tags: mysql, insert, cte

I am trying to write a stored procedure to return a calculated value from a dataset by writing the result to a table.  When I run this code on MySQL 8.0.32, I get an error 1064 Syntax error on the `INSERT INTO` line.

I have tried tweaking this for hours and still can't figure out why it's an error.  If I simply Select the `AVG(Pct_Saved)` without the insert to display in the results pane, it works fine.  But I need to save the answer to a table to return to the calling query.  It also gets the same error if I try to hardcode the table name instead of using a variable.  The select runs from the results of a nested CTE, so I don't know if that could point to a problem.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
SET @userid = LEFT(USER(),POSITION('@' in USER())-1);
SET @TempTblName = CONCAT('TEMP',@userid);
-- SELECT @TempTblName;
# Define the temparary table for the results
SET @SQLExec = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', 'TEMP',@userid,' (Avg_Savings_Pct DECIMAL(6,2), Avg_ROI_Pct DECIMAL(6,2))');
SELECT @SQLExec;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQLExec;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
-- 

WITH CTE 
AS 
( 
SELECT
    576_VMC_Sol_Savings_Pct AS ctePct_Saved,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 576_VMC_Sol_Savings_Pct) AS row_n
    FROM v_vmc_summary
),

iqr AS
 (
    SELECT
    ctePct_Saved AS Pct_Saved,
    (
        SELECT ctePct_Saved AS quartile_break
        FROM CTE
        WHERE row_n = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM v_vmc_summary)*0.75)
            ) AS q_three,
    (
        SELECT ctePct_Saved AS quartile_break
        FROM CTE
        WHERE row_n = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM v_vmc_summary)*0.25)
            ) AS q_one,
    1.5 * ((
        SELECT ctePct_Saved AS quartile_break
        FROM CTE
        WHERE row_n = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM v_vmc_summary)*0.75)
            ) - (
            SELECT ctePct_Saved AS quartile_break
            FROM CTE
            WHERE row_n = FLOOR((SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM v_vmc_summary)*0.25)
            )) AS outlier_range
    FROM CTE
 )
    INSERT INTO @TempTblName (Avg_Savings_Pct)
    SELECT AVG(Pct_Saved) 
     FROM iqr
        WHERE Pct_Saved >= q_one - outlier_range AND
        Pct_Saved <= q_three + outlier_range;
```

EDIT:
Moving the INSERT as suggested still returns the same error:

```
--  INSERT INTO @TempTblName (Avg_Savings_Pct)
    SELECT AVG(Pct_Saved) INTO @TempTblName (Avg_Savings_Pct)
     FROM iqr
        WHERE Pct_Saved >= q_one - outlier_range AND
        Pct_Saved <= q_three + outlier_range;
```

Comment: The CTE(s) must precede the `SELECT` clause, not `INSERT`, which is [described in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions).

Comment: I have tried that other format and get the same error. I thought the documentation indicated that the SELECT INTO format could only update variables, and instead referred to INSERT ... INTO.

Comment: Please provide the text of the error message.  1064 is very good about pointing at the exact location of the problem with `near '...`.

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html says:

> A WITH clause is permitted in these contexts:
>
> - At the beginning of SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
>
>   ```
>     WITH ... SELECT ...
>     WITH ... UPDATE ...
>     WITH ... DELETE ...
>   ```

I.e. not before an `INSERT`.

However, you can use `INSERT INTO <table> WITH <cte> SELECT ...`

---

Re your comments:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTblName (Avg_Savings_Pct)
```

You can't use a user variable as an identifier.

```
SELECT AVG(Pct_Saved) INTO @TempTblName (Avg_Savings_Pct)
```

That's not any supported syntax. You can `SELECT INTO @variable` but that only assigns a scalar value to the variable. You just made up this syntax without any supporting evidence that it means anything. Programming doesn't work that way; you can't just make up some syntax at random and hope it magically does what you have in mind.

Here's how to select into a table:

```
INSERT INTO mytable -- use an identifier, not a variable
  WITH CTE AS ( ... ), iqr AS ( ... )
  SELECT AVG(Pct_Saved) 
  FROM iqr
  WHERE Pct_Saved >= q_one - outlier_range AND
        Pct_Saved <= q_three + outlier_range;
```

Comment: Can you point to an example of that?  I've tried that syntax and I'm still missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I have tried replacing the variable with the actual table name, which also did not work, but I'll try this again based on your example.  As a secondary issue, is there a way to use a variable or construct for a table name?  For example, I want to store the results in a table that is unique to the user running the query, so that other users running the same query don't overwrite some common table.

Comment: In SQL, identifiers must be fixed in the query before it's parsed. So you have to format your SQL query as a string, including all the identifiers, before you submit it to the RDBMS. So it must be done in the client application, by means like sprintf() or string concatenation or client variable interpolation into the string. Then the string is used as an SQL query.